# Android Nougat multi-window minHeight

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Anyone tried setting minimum Height for the app to have in Nougat multi-window mode ?

Tried this,

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"
        android:defaultWidth="600dp"
        android:gravity="top|end"
        android:minHeight="450dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />
</activity>
```

My reference was this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

But, didn't found any difference.

App working as normal in multi-window.
No difference in the minimum Height for the app.

Answer (score 1):

In split-screen mode, `minHeight` does not change the minimum height of the pane that the activity is in. However, quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#configuring):

> If the user moves the divider in split-screen mode to make an activity smaller than the specified minimum, the system crops the activity to the size the user requests.

Without `minHeight`, if the user moves the divider and resizes your activity's pane, your activity is resized.

With `minHeight`, if the user moves the divider and now your activity's pane is smaller than the `minHeight`, your activity still renders into a `minHeight` canvas. However, then that canvas is cropped, so the user only sees the top `minHeight` of it.

Eventually, in free-form window mode, `minHeight` might behave more like what you would expect from the attribute name, where the activity's window cannot be resized smaller than the designated height.

Comment: Much clear... Works the same if the app supports only one layout. But if different layout is there for landscape and when we moves the divider to a lower value, app will switch to the other orientation. How can we handle this ?

Comment: @Vineeth: Really? I have not tried this. I will have to run some experiments.

Comment: Do try this. App with different layout for portrait & landscape. Its so annoying to switch to the other orientation when divider is dragged to a smaller value.

Comment: @Vineeth: Sorry for the delay. I just reproduced your results. There is nothing that you can do about this directly. Either make sure that the transition between portrait and landscape layouts is not too jarring, or handle this configuration change yourself via `android:configChanges` and `onConfigurationChanged()`. There, you can at least consider trying to do things differently in multi-window mode (via `isInMultWindowMode()`), though [that method is unreliable](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/06/07/isinmultiwindowmode-race-condition.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But doing that in my app is causing performance issues since a TextClock is running in the screen & even an AlarmManager as well. I'm already working with that as you mentioned, to get rid of this & the resource shortage issue while in multi window mode.

Comment: @CommonsWare when I set the minHeight only some part of the screen is visible but when I remove minHeight total screen appears .The screen is scrollable. This happens only on mobile device but works fine on tablet. Can you please help.

Comment: @Vinay: I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of app you actually need to modify AOSP, so that it will effectively set the divider size as per your requirement. You will then have to flash your device with modified AOSP code.